# Why does Spark infer a binary instead of an Array[Byte] when creating a DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, binary, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

In principle, I have a `DataFrame` that consists of the *"Name"* and *"Values"* fields. The first field is a `String`, while the second is an `Array[Byte]`.

What I want to do with each record of this `DataFrame` is to apply any function, using a `UDF` and create a new column. This works perfectly when *"Values"* is an `Array[Int]`. However, when it is an `Array[Byte]`, the following error appears:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(Values)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array<tinyint> type, however, '`Values`' is of binary type.;;
'Project [Name#47, Values#48, UDF(Values#48) AS TwoTimes#56]
+- Project [_1#44 AS Name#47, _2#45 AS Values#48]
+- SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class 
org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._1, true) AS _1#44, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._2 AS _2#45]
  +- ExternalRDD [obj#43]
```

The full code is the following:

```
scala> val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("one", Array[Byte](1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), ("two", Array[Byte](6, 7, 8, 9, 10)))).toDF("Name", "Values")
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Name: string, Values: binary]

scala> df1.show
+----+----------------+
|Name|          Values|
+----+----------------+
| one|[01 02 03 04 05]|
| two|[06 07 08 09 0A]|
+----+----------------+

scala> val twice = udf { (values: Seq[Byte]) =>
   |     val result = Array.ofDim[Byte](values.length)
   |     for (i <- values.indices)
   |         result(i) = (2 * values(i).toInt).toByte
   |     result
   | }
twice: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,BinaryType,Some(List(ArrayType(ByteType,false))))

scala> val df2 = df1.withColumn("TwoTimes", twice('Values))
```

I understand that an error like this arises due to the wrong data type (expected: `Array[Byte]`, however it finds a `Binary`), but what I do not understand is why Spark has inferred my `Array[Byte]` as a `Binary`. Can someone explain to me, please?

If I had to use `Binary` instead of `Array[Byte]`, how should I handle it within my `UDF`?

I clarify that my original `UDF` does not use a trivial `for` loop. I understand that in this example, this could be replaced by the `map` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Spark, `Array[Byte]` is represented as a `BinaryType`. From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/types/BinaryType.html) we can see:

> public class BinaryType extends DataType
>   The data type representing `Array[Byte]` values. Please use the singleton DataTypes.BinaryType.

Hence, `Array[Byte]` and `Binary` are the same, however, there are some differences between these and `Seq[Byte]` which results in an error.

To fix the issue, simply replace `Seq[Byte]` with `Array[Byte]` in the udf:

```
val twice = udf { (values: Array[Byte]) =>
  val result = Array.ofDim[Byte](values.length)
  for (i <- values.indices)
    result(i) = (2 * values(i).toInt).toByte
  result
}
```